# How to build vim80 from source with python2 and 3 support?

Tags: python, vim

I want to compile vim80 following the instruction on the webpage.

[build vim80 from source with python2 and 3 support](https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/wiki/Building-Vim-from-source)

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr
```

How to customize it according to my environment?
1.For python2.7

```
 ls /usr/lib/python2.7 |grep config
config-x86_64-linux-gnu
_sysconfigdata.py
_sysconfigdata.pyc
_sysconfigdata.pyo
sysconfig.py
sysconfig.pyc
sysconfig.pyo
```

2.For python3

```
sudo find /  -name  'config' |grep python3
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/navigator_updater/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/help/js/mathjax/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-3.1.4-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/spyder-3.1.4-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/spyder/utils/help/js/mathjax/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/astropy-1.3.2-np112py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/astropy/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/traitlets-4.3.2-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/traitlets/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/anaconda-navigator-1.6.2-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/navigator-updater-0.1.0-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/navigator_updater/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-5.0.0-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/config
/home/debian8/anaconda3/pkgs/notebook-5.0.0-py36_0/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/config
```

More concretely,how to change the three lines for my os?

```
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/usr/lib/python3.5/config \
```

Here is my try for python2 and 3 support.

```
./configure --with-features=huge \
            --enable-multibyte \
            --enable-rubyinterp=yes \
            --enable-pythoninterp=yes \
            --with-python-config-dir=/usr/lib/python2.7/config-x86_64-linux-gnu \
            --enable-python3interp=yes \
            --with-python3-config-dir=/home/debian8/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/anaconda_navigator/config \
            --enable-perlinterp=yes \
            --enable-luainterp=yes \
            --enable-gui=gtk2 --enable-cscope --prefix=/usr
```

It is unlucky that no support python2 or python3 for this configuration after make install.

```
vim --version|grep python
+cryptv          +linebreak       -python          +vreplace
+cscope          +lispindent      -python3         +wildignore
```

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is here. Were you expecting to see something other than "+python" and "+python3" ?

Comment: yes, +python and +python3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./configure   --prefix=/usr/local/           \
                       --with-features=huge  \
                       --enable-multibyte    \
                       --enable-cscope=yes   \
                       --enable-perlinterp=yes     \
                       --enable-rubyinterp=yes     \
                       --with-ruby-command=/usr/bin/ruby     \
                       --enable-luainterp=yes                \
                       --enable-pythoninterp=yes             \
                       --enable-python3interp=yes            \
                       --enable-tclinterp=yes                   \
                       --enable-gui=auto --enable-gnome-check   \  
                       --enable-xim --enable-fontset            \
                        --with-x --with-compiledby=$USER
```